# Linq Query Optimization for faster results

Tags: c#, linq

I have a winform with a button and a datagridview.

The scenario is:

I have a winform:

```
                   using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.ComponentModel;
        using System.Data;
        using System.Drawing;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Windows.Forms;

        namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
        {
            public partial class Form1 : Form
            {
                public Form1()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                    CreateItems();
                }

                private List<Store> stores = new List<Store>();

                public void CreateItems()
                {

                    Store newStore1 = new Store();
                    newStore1.StoreName = "My Store 1";
                    newStore1.City = "My City 1";
                    newStore1.PlannedSales = 10;
                    newStore1.RealizedSales = 5;
                    newStore1.SalesDate = new DateTime(2012, 01, 12, 12, 30, 54, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

                    Store newStore2 = new Store();
                    newStore2.StoreName = "My Store 2";
                    newStore2.City = "My City 2";
                    newStore2.PlannedSales = 200000;
                    newStore2.RealizedSales = 250000;
                    newStore2.SalesDate = new DateTime(2012, 04, 12, 12, 30, 54, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

                    Store newStore3 = new Store();
                    newStore3.StoreName = "My Store 3";
                    newStore3.City = "My City 3";
                    newStore3.PlannedSales = 100000;
                    newStore3.RealizedSales = 10000;
                    newStore3.SalesDate = new DateTime(2012, 05, 12, 12, 30, 54, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

                    Store newStore4 = new Store();
                    newStore4.StoreName = "My Store 1";
                    newStore4.City = "My City 1";
                    newStore4.PlannedSales = 20;
                    newStore4.RealizedSales = 10;
                    newStore4.SalesDate = new DateTime(2012, 02, 12, 12, 30, 54, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);


                    Store newStore5 = new Store();
                    newStore5.StoreName = "My Store 1";
                    newStore5.City = "My City 1";
                    newStore5.PlannedSales = 30;
                    newStore5.RealizedSales = 20;
                    newStore5.SalesDate = new DateTime(2012, 03, 12, 12, 30, 54, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);



                    stores.Add(newStore1);
                    stores.Add(newStore2);
                    stores.Add(newStore3);
                    stores.Add(newStore4);
                    stores.Add(newStore5);
                }

                private void btnQuery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    var query1 = stores.GroupBy(x => new
                    {
                        x.City,
                        x.StoreName,
                        x.SalesDate.Year,
                        x.SalesDate.Month

                    }).Select(group => new
                    {
                        Planned = group.Sum(x => x.PlannedSales),
                        Realised = group.Sum(x => x.RealizedSales),
                        Count = group.Count(),
                        City = group.Key.City,
                        StoreName = group.Key.StoreName,
                        Year = group.Key.Year,
                        Month = group.Key.Month
                    }).OrderBy(x => x.Year).ThenBy(x => x.Month).Where(x => x.StoreName.Equals("My Store 1"));

                    List<Store> total = new List<Store>();

                    foreach (var value in query1)
                    {
                        Store newStore = new Store()
                        {
                            MonthYear = value.Month.ToString() + " - " + value.Year.ToString(),
                            RealizedSales = value.Realised,
                            PlannedSales = value.Planned

                        };
                        total.Add(newStore);
                    };


                    var query2 = total.Select((s, i) => new
                    {
                        MonthYear = s.MonthYear,
                        RealizedSales = s.RealizedSales + total.Take(i).Sum(sa => sa.RealizedSales),
                        PlannedSales = s.PlannedSales + total.Take(i).Sum(sa => sa.PlannedSales)
                    });

                    List<Store> totalFinal = new List<Store>();


                    foreach (var value in query2)
                    {
                        Store newStore = new Store()
                        {
                            MonthYear = value.MonthYear,
                            RealizedSales = value.RealizedSales,
                            PlannedSales = value.PlannedSales
                        };
                        totalFinal.Add(newStore);
                    };


                    dataGridView1.DataSource = totalFinal;

                }
            }

            public class Store
            {
                public string StoreName { get; set; }
                public string City { get; set; }

                public int PlannedSales { get; set; }
                public int RealizedSales { get; set; }

                public DateTime SalesDate { get; set; }

                public string MonthYear { get; set; }

            }
        }
```

When the form is instantiated, the method CreateItems is called. This method will populate a **List** with some demo **Store** data.

When the button from the form is pressed, than the **List stores** is queried with Linq in a way that will return all the **PlannedSales** and **RealizedSales** per **MonthYear** from my **List stores** WHERE the **StoreName** = My Store 1

An example of the query result is here: http://i49.tinypic.com/vz1c6.jpg

Any idea how to optimize this query to make it more simpler but get the same result?

Basically I need to return all planned and realized sales per month-year for a specific store name only!

Thanks!

Comment: where and how is it lacking that you think it needs optimization?

Comment: i am using this in a silverlight sharepoint webpart and is quite slow when querying lots of items from a list and you have big numbers. for example some other queries works fine except this one and another query that is pretty much similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be as easy as:

```
var totalPlanned = 0;
var totalRealized = 0;
var result = stores.Where(s => s.StoreName.Equals("My Store 1"))
                   .Select(s => {
                        totalPlanned += s.PlannedSales;
                        totalRealized += s.RealizedSales;
                        return new Store(){
                           MonthYear = s.SalesDate.ToString("MM - yyyy"),
                           PlannedSales = totalPlanned,
                           RealizedSales = totalRealized

                        };
                    });
```

Live example showing this new code alongside your original to show same result: http://rextester.com/PAF27531

Comment: That works for the demo data, but wouldn't get the same result if the data weren't ordered by date or if there were multiple stores with the same city, name, and date.

Answer (score -1):

```
from s in stores
where s.StoreName == "My Store 1"
group s by new { s.StoreName, s.SalesDate.Year, s.SalesDate.Month } into g
select new
{
g.Key.StoreName,
MonthYear = g.Key.Year.ToString() + " - " + g.Key.Month.ToString(),
Planned = g.Sum(st => st.PlannedSales),
Realized = g.Sum(st => st.RealizedSales)
}
```

Comment: This gives a totally different result to the OP's original. http://rextester.com/XQOO40579